# Can't merge 2 images using PIL

Tags: python, image, graphics, python-imaging-library

I am merging 2 images:

```
 from PIL import Image, ImageOps
    mask = Image.open('/root/test/grid.png').convert('L')
    im = Image.open('/root/test/longcat.jpg')
    output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
    output.putalpha(mask)
    output.save('/root/test/output.png')
```

If I save as .png I can see grid but if I save as .jpeg .gif there is no grid image. 
Also I can't get color of `grid(getpixel((10, 6)))`

Comment: There is a known issue with PIL and alpha blending in some image formats.  Have you tried pillow?

Comment: Thanks. No.I haven`t how it can be done in  pillow ?

Comment: I am not sure that it can but know that pillow is under more active development than PIL so is more likely to have the issue resolved.  Since Pillow is a fork of PIL the API is generally the same.